# Troubleshooting x86 GAS syntax code

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I'm getting errors when I compile this function, specifically in the Func body where I'm trying to multiply an int pointer by 3 and load it back into the pointer. (i.e *i = 3 * (*i))

```
//Author Matthew Cabrera

#define FSIZE 8

// Prologue
.text
.global istr
istr:
   subl $FSIZE, %esp   //frame space
//Load Paramaters
   movl FSIZE+4(%esp), %eax   //1st param
   movl FSIZE+8(%esp), %edx   //2nd param
   movl FSIZE+12(%esp), %ecx  //3rd param
//Func body 
   leal (%ecx, %ecx, 2), %ecx //*i = 3 * (*i)
   subl %edx, %eax  //This is the 1st param - 2nd param. No errors here.
//Epilogue
   add  $FSIZE, %esp    //restore stack ptr
   ret
```

Effectively, the c function would look like

```
int istr(int a, int b, int *i){
    *i = 3 * (*i);
    return (a-b);
}
```

Comment: _ECX_ will be a pointer to a value, not the value itself. You'll need to dereference it and get the value, do the computation on it and then store it back to the memory location pointed to by _ECX_

Comment: How do I dereference it, exactly? Sorry I'm still getting aquatinted with assembly.

Comment: You do it the same way as you dereference `esp` to get the parameters. _I.e._ _e.g._ `movl (%ecx), %ebx`